# Как при инициализации класса передать аргументом этот же класс?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу сделать тип данных, в котором используется этот же тип данных.

```
class Message:
    def __init__(self, text: Message):
        self.text = text
```

Такой код не хочет работать, есть ли какое-то решение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сейчас этот код вызывает исключение `NameError`. Так происходит потому, что Вы пытаетесь обратиться к типу `Message`. Но тип `Message` ещё не объявлен. Избежать ошибки можно, передав имя класса строкой:

```py
class Message:
    def __init__(self, text: 'Message'):
        self.text = text
```

---

Но есть одна проблема — как Вы создадите первый экземпляр класса, если для его инициализации нужен другой экземпляр этого же класса? Предлагаю сделать параметр `text` необязательным:

```py
class Message:
    def __init__(self, text: 'Message'=None):
        if text is not None:
            self.text = text

message1 = Message()
message2 = Message(message1)
```

Comment: class Message:       def __init__(self, id: int, reply_message: 'Message'): print(reply_message.id)    Можно будет так сделать, если имя класса будет передано строкой?

Comment: @СашаГоголь Да, можно будет. Аннотации типов не влияют на исполнение кода. Вы можете не указывать тип, и код будет работать так же

Comment: Начиная с Python 3.7 можно еще `from __future__ import annotations` использовать, см. [PEP-563](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/)